# Chrome/Firefox/IE Customize HTML5 validation message: Consistent look and feel and message

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I customize HTML5 validation message such that it becomes consistent across all web browsers? Currently, the default error message for required "Please fill out this field" appears in a rectangular box (in IE) and in firefox it the same message popups-up in a rectangular rounded at corners and in Chrome the message is suffixed with orange icon "i".

I want to make this message popup consistent across all browsers.

```
<input id="username" type="text" required ="required">
```

The required attribute in HTML5 will popup the message "Please fill out this field"

**Edit**
Is "kendo-ui/tooltip" open source and free and used for commercial purpose? Is there any other way to do the same without using kendo-ui?

Can this be handled using `jpqery $( document ).tooltip({})` or `jquery dialog` and binding it to different events? For example, when `enter key` is pressed this event should run the jquery validation code and check whether the textfield is filled or not. If it is not filled then message should popup stating "Please fill out the field". Later on, when the number is entered the message would disappear.

Alternately, can we make the pop-up bubble appear similar to the one appearing in chrome across all browsers?

I was able fiddle with dialog util little bit not sure how to go ahead with onfocus when user is trying to enter field values again(re-bind etc).

```
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
   $(".testing").keydown(function (event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13'){
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        }
    }); 
    $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" class="testing" /><br />

<div id="dialog" title="title">
  <p>Please fill this field</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">validate</button>


</body>
</html>
```

In relation to this issue, I have also found Validate.js recently.

Comment: please show what you have done

Comment: To do this thoroughly this is highly non-trivial. Of course you can hook into the `validate` event, but then you have to do all the validation message generation yourself. I opted for the hard path and completely rewrote the HTML5 validation API in JS: https://hyperform.js.org/. This may or may not be right for you. It's written for users with lots of forms + custom validation to handle.

Comment: @Boldewyn hats off to you for that API and thats exactly the non-trivial work I want to accomplish. Well, in my case, the requirement is not that complex but to just show a message "Please fill the input field " to the user when he has not filled a mandatory field and has hit the enter key to submit the form (this message need to be consistent across all browsers), I want to get rid of blur hover all other stuff. I know it is hard labor but appreciate if you'd let me know the starting point to write a lib of my own for this custom validation alone.

Comment: @Boldewyn your js is quite comprehensive lib for form validation. After going thru your code on github I realized that I only need 5% of that code. I have one question can I use them in my code (esp. the logic)? Have to do lot of testing and confirmation that all scenarios are covered... Would need from Catlog one message Value missing and some functions like these ignored keypress handler, keypress handler, ignored click handler, click handler, uncatch submit

catalog

Comment: @yeppe the code is published under the MIT license, so, yes, you can basically use it however you want (perhaps add a note somewhere, where the ideas are from...). However, if you really only want to customize validation messages, you might be better off with a minimal approach like https://jsbin.com/taqebi/edit?js,output

Comment: Don't! Trying to make browser-specific elements appear the same across all browsers is not only futile, it also damages accessibility and degrades user experience. Chrome users, for example, expect form feedback to look the same; that is what the user expects. When you change that, you do nothing to enhance the UX, you just add confusion for the user.

Comment: @SethWarburton Thanks for your concern, rightly so, I have delayed this browser-specify appearance to some other time for now.